# ews exchange web services License

Tags: licensing, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want develop email client using [EWS exchange web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). Does it requires any license from Microsoft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EWS** itself does not require special licensing - it is bundled along with **Exchange Server**. All you need is an [**Exchange Server**](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/licensing-exchange-server-email.aspx) license or **[Exchange Online](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/licensing-exchange-online-email.aspx)** license to consume **EWS**. What you build around **EWS** (*mobile app, web app, native app, etc.*) is entirely up to you.

Comment: I am exactly looking for this. Thank you SliverNinja